# React Native Fetch Blob creating issue while pod install on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fetch-blob, rn-fetch-blob

I've install `react-native-fetch-blob` on react-native `version 0.60.5`.While I run `pod install`, the error appears as you can see in the **[image: screenshot]**

Kindly guide me on how to **resolve** this **issue**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to `./node-module/react-native-fetch-blob/react-native-fetch-blob.podspec` & change

```
s.dependency 'React/Core'
```

to

```
s.dependency 'React-Core'
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this instead for the new version of react native 0.60 and up https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

Answer (score 0):

change dependency React/Core to React-Core using the following command

```
grep -rl "s.dependency 'React/Core'" node_modules/ | xargs sed -i '' 's=React/Core=React-Core=g'
```

or

you can go to node modules at path `./node-module/react-native-fetch-blob/react-native-fetch-blob.podspec` and change `React/Core` to `React-Core`