# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core"

Tags: ios, reactjs, native, pod-install

when I start pod install
the result :

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
In Podfile:
react-native-fetch-blob (from `../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob`) was resolved to 0.10.6, which depends on
React/Core

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core`.

You have either:

- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

I try to fix like
pod repo update* + pod update
remove podfile.lock
still not working
thanks advance
pod file is:

```html
platform :ios, '10.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'delivery_partner' do
  # Pods for delivery_partner
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'




  target 'delivery_partnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'delivery_partner-tvOS' do
  # Pods for delivery_partner-tvOS

  target 'delivery_partner-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

package.json is :

> 

```html
    {
  "name": "dry_partner",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.0.0-alpha.25",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.0.8",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "firebase": "^7.1.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view-forked": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.5.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- I change   line
in package file

"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.0.0-alpha.25"

with

"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.13.0-alpha.25"

2- cd iOS

3- pod update

every things work fine

thanks

Answer (score 15):

Go to `./node-module/react-native-fetch-blob/react-native-fetch-blob.podspec` & change

```
s.dependency 'React/Core'
```

to

```
s.dependency 'React-Core'
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

all credits go to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130581/8715452

Answer (score 9):

This command will fix the issue run this command in the root directory of your project and it will replace "React/Core" with "React-Core" in all the npm modules:

```
grep -rl "s.dependency 'React/Core'" node_modules/ | xargs sed -i '' 's=React/Core=React-Core=g'
```

Comment: Nice! Worked like a charm. After this, I ran `$ pod install` and it finally worked after trying to troubleshoot for too long

Answer (score 1):

I am using `rn-fetch-blob` (which replaced the `react-native-fetch-blob` repo) and needed to upgrade from v. 0.10.15 --> 0.10.16 via

`npm i --save rn-fetch-blob@0.10.16`

I needed to do this due to upgrading RN from 0.59.9 to 0.60.6. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Pod got installed after increasing the minimum deployment target version to 13 in ios->podfile.

platform :ios, '13.0'